# Inject beans by generic type?

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection

Is it possible (with `Spring`) to inject beans by the generic type of a class automatically?

Example:

```
class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyWebServicePort get() {
        return new Webservice().getPort();
    }
}

abstract class BaseClient<T> {
    @Autowired
    T port;
}

class MyClientService extends BaseClient<MyWebServicePort> {
    void run() {
        //use port, which is instanceof MyWebServicePort.class
    }
}
```

Is it possible, or would I have to explicitly inject each port in each client service implementation manually?

Comment: There are a lot of internal classes that handle resolving generics to types including the org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver. You may be able to use the @Qualifier annotation and resolve it yourself by implementing a org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterFactory. I'm not an expert in this area though, merely interested.